# challenge password in SCEP

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, digital-certificate, client-certificates

What is the purpose of challenge password in simple certificate enrollment protocol (SCEP)?

My understanding is that it is used to authenticate devices.

My question is : How it is different from authentication done by using public and private key pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a certificate is compromised (the private key is stolen, etc.) the
certificate needs to be revoked as it will remain valid till the end of it's
term.

Any administrator with access to a cert can revoke the cert. If a challenge
password was specified during the certificate signing request that password
will be required before the cert can be revoked.

So, it seems the sole purpose of the challenge password is to prevent
revocation by someone without the password.

Comment: so purpose of challenge password is to protect the certificate from unauthorized access?

Answer (score 4):

Challenge password is(/may be) used in the enrollment process. As stated in [SCEP specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nourse-scep-23) (section 2.3):

> PKCS#10 [RFC2986] specifies a PKCS#9 [RFC2985] challengePassword
> attribute to be sent as part of the enrollment request.  Inclusion of
> the challengePassword by the SCEP client is OPTIONAL and allows for
> unauthenticated authorization of enrollment requests.  The PKCS#7
> [RFC2315] envelope protects the privacy of the challenge password.
>
> When utilizing the challengePassword, the server distributes a shared
> secret to the requester which will uniquely associate the enrollment
> request with the requester.  The distribution of the secret must be
> private: only the end entity should know this secret.  The actual
> binding mechanism between the requester and the secret is subject to
> the server policy and implementation.

In section 2.5 draft states:

> The challengePassword MAY be used to automatically authorize the
> request.

SCEP draft states in section 2.8:

> SCEP does not specify a method to request certificate revocation.

but when challenge password was used in the enrollment process then:

> In order to revoke a certificate, the requester must contact the CA
> server operator using a non-SCEP defined mechanism.  Although the
> PKCS#10 [RFC2986] challengePassword is used by SCEP for enrollment
> authorization (see Enrollment authorization (Section 2.3)) this does
> not inhibit the CA server from  maintaining a record of the
> challengePassword to use during subsequent revocation operations as
> implied by [RFC2985].

Answer (score 0):

SCEP is used to issue certificates to devices (mostly in an untrusted network). The admin will generate challenge password and send it to the user via mail. The SCEP server knows about this challenge password. (We can ask SCEP Server to generate a challenge password and give it to the admin which he shares with respective person). When a device requests SCEP server for certificate with this challenge password, the SCEP server can validate the challenge password and issue certificate.

Actually the device makes first request to get CA cert of the server. It validates the CA Cert. Then the device generates private and public key locally which is what, for instance, iOS MDM agent does. Then a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) is sent to the SCEP server with challenge password. The SCEP Server validates challenge password and now signs the device's public key with its private key. The result is the certificate.

Reference:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/public-key-infrastructure-pki/116167-technote-scep-00.html